# jqでjsonからjson配列を作り直す

Tags: jq

このようなjsonがあった時に、

```
{
  "taro": {
    "favorite": {
      "fruits": [
        "orange"
      ]
    }
  },"jiro": {
    "favorite": {
      "fruits": [
        "apple",
        "banana",
        "orange"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

jqで以下のようなjson配列を作り直すには、どのようなコマンドを打てば良いでしょうか。

```
{
  "name": "taro",
  "favorite_fruit":[
    "orange"
 ]
},{
  "name": "jiro",
  "favorite_fruit": [
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "orange"
 ]
}
```

Comment: `to_entries` で key-value pair に変換してから再構成してみてはどうでしょうか。`jq -r 'to_entries|.[]|.name=.key|.favorite_fruit=.value.favorite.fruits|del(.key,.value)' favorite.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_entries`から`*`演算子で再起マージが使えるんでないかと。

```
$ <test.json jq '[to_entries[] | {name: .key} * {favorite_fruit: .value.favorite.fruits}]'
[
  {
    "name": "taro",
    "favorite_fruit": [
      "orange"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "jiro",
    "favorite_fruit": [
      "apple",
      "banana",
      "orange"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: 再起マージするまでもなく普通に`{name: .key, favorite_fruit: .value.favorite.fruits}`でいけましたね。ボケてました。